# Copy some column and add value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. In first i have 3 column in the second lot.
I need to fill in the table with the other two values of the table and one value.
For a copy, I use the following, but i dont know how add 
some value (example '3') in the third column.
Just start learn SQL
Sorry for noobie question.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (page_id, price)
SELECT page_id, price FROM `table2` WHERE `manufacturer_id` = 10
```

Comment: Couldn't understand your question... can you rephrase it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (page_id, price, third_column)
SELECT page_id, price, 3
FROM table2
WHERE manufacturer_id = 10
```

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank for your help my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You can add static columns to the `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT page_id, price, '3' 
FROM `table2` 
WHERE `manufacturer_id` = 10
```

Note that you'll need to add the third column into your column list for the `INSERT`